# Draw polynomial regression line that summarizes over grouped distributions

Tags: r, ggplot2, non-linear-regression

Let's say I have this kind of data, with `value` observations grouped by three levels of `size`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  size = c(3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
  position = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5),
  value = c(1,2,2.5,
            -0.5,0.5,-0.5,1,
            1.7,2,2.5,1.6,1.9)
)
```

I can draw polynomial regression lines for each `size` level:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = position, y = value, color = factor(size))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), se = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Index", y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal()
```

resulting in this plot:

[image]

What I need **in addition to the three separate lines** is one line that, respecting the grouping, summarizes the three distributions; i.e., a regression line that shows how the `value` variable distributes across the three levels. (How) can that be done?

Comment: You mean adding a new geom_smooth layer and setting color manually to, say, "black" outside `aes`?

Comment: Yes, for example. But the grouping needs to remain intact (and at the same time abstracted away from, which makes it pretty tough, as if to say, "the 'grand' distribution **underlying** these three separate distributions is this"

Comment: I'm not sure what that means Chris. You want a _single_ line that represents a polynomial regression on all the points, but in some way it needs to respect grouping? In what sense could a single line do that? Do you mean using group as a random effect?

Comment: I'm not too familar with mixed-effects modelling but I'm almost certain that one such model will be needed

Comment: Please note that I've updated the 'data' by including a third variable `position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how well-specified the problem is, but there are a couple of options to consider. One is to use a mixed effects model, where the best fitting polynomial is calculated for all the points, but the intercept is allowed to vary per group:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(size = factor(size)) %>%
  group_by(size) %>% 
  mutate(x = row_number())

mod <- lmer(value ~ poly(x, 2) + (1|size), df)
newdata <- expand.grid(x = seq(1, 5, 0.1), 
                       size = factor("Fixed effect of index"))
newdata$value <- predict(mod, newdata, allow.new.levels = TRUE)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, color = size)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), se = FALSE) +
  geom_line(data = newdata, linetype = 2) + 
  labs(x = "Index", y = "Value") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red3", "blue3", "green4", "black")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Conceptually, this means that we are showing the single best-fitting polynomial that could be "slid" up and down the plot so it is the same shape for each group, but at a different height. This plot should illustrate what I mean:

```r
newdata2 <- expand.grid(x = seq(1, 5, 0.1), 
                        size = factor(c(3:5, "Fixed effect of index")))
newdata2$value <- predict(mod, newdata2, allow.new.levels = TRUE)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, color = size, linetype = size)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = newdata2) + 
  labs(x = "Index", y = "Value") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red3", "blue3", "green4", "black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 1, 1, 2)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

A simpler approach of course, is to add a separate layer showing regression on all groups at once:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, color = size)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), se = FALSE) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), 
              aes(color = "All groups"), se = FALSE, linetype = 2) + 
  labs(x = "Index", y = "Value") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red3", "blue3", "green4", "black")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

It seems from the comments that this isn't exactly what you're looking for.

If neither of these are what you are after, please add a bit of clarification.

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a million for this: so, to be sure, the broken line in the upper plot is the best approximation to a summary of the three colored lines, correct?

Comment: Not really @ChrisRuehlemann. The problem is that "the best approximation of a summary of the three lines" isn't really all that well defined. There are different ways to approach it, and it really depends on what you're trying to show. I would have thought that the last method is more intuitive: this is the polynomial that fits all the data points best regardless of group. The mixed effects model preserves the overall shape of the relationship while acknowledging different baselines. You could also take a weighted mean of each line. "Best" doesn't really mean anything without context.